# Question related to vector space of solutions of a differential equations system.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have some doubts  regarding the proof of the statement:

The set of solutions of the system $$X'=A(t)X$$ where $A(t):I \subset \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is continuous, forms an $n$-dimensional vector space.

Asssuming the set is a vector space, I could show that it is of dimension $n$. Now, I also could prove that: $i)$ it is closed under sum, $(i)$ it is closed under multiplication by scalars and $(iii)$ the zero function is in it:

$(i)$ Let $X_1(t)$ and $X_2(t)$ be solutions of the given system, then $$(X_1(t)+X_2(t))'=X_1(t)'+X_2(t)'=AX_1(t)+AX_2(t)=A(X_1(t)+X_2(t),$$ this means $X_1(t)+X_2(t))$ is a solution of the system as well.

$(ii)$ Let $c \in \mathbb R$ and $X(t)$ be a solution of the system, we have $$(cX(t))'=cX'(t)=c(AX(t))=A(cX(t)),$$ this implies $cX(t)$ is also a solution of the system.

$(iii)$ Consider $0$ the zero function from $I$ to $\mathbb R^n$, then $$0'=0=A0,$$
so the zero function is a solution of the given system.

If the set of solutions was a subset of a some vector space, then by proving those three points I could affirm that the set is a subspace, or a vector space itself; if I can't find a vector space that contains this set, then I have to prove other properties that the set must satisfied in order to be a vector space. I think that considering the space of continuous functions from $I$ to $\mathbb R^n$ is sufficient but I would like to check if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution $X(t)$ to 
$$
X^\prime(t)=A(t)X(t)
$$
is a map $X:I\to \Bbb R^n$. Note that the collection $V$ of all maps $I\to\Bbb R^n$ is an $\Bbb R$-vector space (check this!). Hence we may apply the [One-Step Vector Subspace Test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test) to the subcollection $S\subset V$ given by
$$
S=\{X\in V: X^\prime(t)=A(t)X(t)\,\forall t\in I\}
$$
This is basically what you've already done and your details look correct.

It's worth learning the One-Step Vector Subspace test, as it's the most efficient way to check if a subcollection of a vector space is a subspace.